# Duplicate records added to the table despite the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: python, database, duplicates

How do I resolve this duplication error? When I run this program and it displays the items, the items are duplicated every time I run the program.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('products_database') 
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products
          ([product_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [product_name] TEXT, [stock] INTEGER)
          ''')
          
c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices
          ([product_id] INTEGER, [price] REAL,
          FOREIGN KEY([product_id]) REFERENCES products([product_id]))
          ''')
                     
conn.commit()

c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products")
row_count = c.fetchone()[0]

if row_count == 0:              
    c.execute('''
          INSERT OR IGNORE INTO products (product_id, product_name, stock)

                VALUES
                (1,'Dozen free range eggs', 10),
                (2,'Fresh milk 3L', 5),
                (3,'Fresh honey 500g', 20),
                (4,'Cheese slices 750g', 15),
                (5,'Butter 500g', 8)
          ''')

c.execute('''
          INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prices (product_id, price)

                VALUES
                (1, 6.50),
                (2, 7),
                (3, 10),
                (4, 8.50),
                (5, 6)
          ''')

conn.commit()


def display_products():
    print("\nHere are the available items:\n")
    c.execute("SELECT products.product_id, products.product_name, products.stock, prices.price FROM products JOIN prices ON products.product_id = prices.product_id")
    products = c.fetchall()
    for product in products:
        print(f"{product[0]}. {product[1]}: {product[2]} in stock, ${product[3]:.2f} per item")


def main_menu():
    print("\nMain Menu:")
    print("\n0. Quit")
    print("1. Buy products")
    print("2. Admin Login")
    print("\nPlease enter your selection.")
     


choice = None  # Initialise choice variable outside the while loop

while choice != "0":
    main_menu()
    
    choice = input()

    if choice == "0":
        print("Thank you, please come again next time!")
        break
    elif choice == "1":
        display_products()
        product_id = input("\nEnter the number corresponding to the item: ")
        product_id = int(product_id)
        if product_id < 1 or product_id > 5:
            print("Invalid item number. Please try again.")
            continue
        
    elif choice == "2":
        print("Admin Login option selected.")
        # Add your code for admin login functionality here
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")
```

I've tried adding the rowcount and Insert or Ignore but don't know how to resolve this

[Error in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCRRS.png)

[Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyl7Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to these few lines that are not included in the `if` block

```
c.execute('''
          INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prices (product_id, price)

                VALUES
                (1, 6.50),
                (2, 7),
                (3, 10),
                (4, 8.50),
                (5, 6)
          ''')

conn.commit()
```

The root cause is that a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint doesn't prevent from having multiple records referencing the same foreign key.
To allow only one price entry for a given product, you need to make the foreign key field `UNIQUE` or even `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices
          ([product_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [price] REAL,
          FOREIGN KEY([product_id]) REFERENCES products([product_id]))
          ''')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Amir. I've included the image in my original post. I have pasted in your code and ran the program but I get this now. I've added the image in the original post.

Comment: I've ran the program again and I'm still getting the duplication issue

Comment: Thank you, I resolved the issue by deleting the database file and then restarting the program. When I ran it again, it didn't duplicate

Comment: @JuicyTendies the root cause seems to be that the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint doesn't prevent adding such duplicate records. To only allow to add one price record referencing a certain product, the foreign key field also needs to be `UNIQUE`.